# Outputting differences in arrays

Tags: c++

I have to make a code where the user inputs altitude readings and the code is supposed to output total climb, total descent, and net change. This is what I have below. I can't figure out how to code to have it output what I want it to.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int array[2010], n, c, d, swap; //the array

printf("Enter number of elements\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

for (c=0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

for (c=0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
{
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
        if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
        { 
         swap         = array[d];
         array[d]     = array[d+1];
         array[d+1]   = swap;
        }
    }
}

printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n"); //lists in order

for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
    printf("%d\n", array[c]);


// Returns minimum difference between any pair
int findMinDiff(int arr[2010], int n);      //supposed to find differce
{
   // Initialize difference as infinite
   int diff = INT_MAX;

   // Find the min diff by comparing difference
   // of all possible pairs in given array
   for (int d=0; d<n-1; d++)
  for (int j=d+1; j<n; j++)
      if (abs(array[d] - array[d--]) < diff)
            diff = abs(array[d] - array[d--]);
   cout<<"Total Climb "<<diff<<endl;
}


system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: *I really need help and this is due Wednesday!* This is usually a demotivator. It will be better to remove that line. Also, indicate what's the expected output and what is the output you are getting.

Comment: There is `std::sort` if you want to sort numbers. Once sorted, "min_diff" can be done by looking adjacent elements difference.

Comment: Are you sure you're learning C++?  Except for a single `cout`, the code is all `C` programming.

Comment: findMinDiff is in the middle of your main function, c++ provides std::sort, and  with a bit of researching yo may find something for the min/max http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element (then why sorting ?)

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for (int j` loop?  You can find the difference between two elements by using `abs(array[d] - array[d+1])`.  I suggest you calculate the difference once and store into a temporary variable.

Comment: BTW, the "total climb" is not the minimum difference in height; think about it.  The total climb would be the sum of any positive difference between two consecutive entries.  The total descent is the sum of the absolute value of a negative change in height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are sorting the array.  Sorting the array may cause problems in calculating the "total climb" and "total descent".

My understanding is that this assignment is about calculating the difference between two numbers and processing that difference.

```
void Process_Data(int array[2010], unsigned int quantity_of_climbs)
{
  int total_climb = 0;
  int total_descent = 0;
  int minimum_change = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < quantity_of_climbs - 1; ++i)
  {
    const int height_change = array[i] - array[i+1];
    if (height_change > 0) // A "climb"
    {
      total_climb += height_change;
    }
    if (height_change < 0) // A "descent"
    {
      total_descent = (-1) * height_change; // Change from negative to positive.
    }
    const int abs_height_change = abs(height_change);
    if (abs_height_change < minimum_change)
    {
      minimum_change = abs_height_change;
    }
  }
  // Display results
}
```